# With Roslyn, find calling method from string literal parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net, roslyn

I'm trying to use Roslyn to replace some old, slow code in a utility that searches our source code for string literals which are not wrapped in an `X()` function call (things wrapped in `X()` will be be translated).

I was able to use the Syntax Tree to get the string literals quite easily, and identified *most* of the places where they were wrapped in `X()`. What I was doing: given an `LiteralExpressionSyntax` object, I found that this gave me the function call and I could match it with a regular expression.

`s.Parent.Parent.Parent.ToFullString()`

I quickly ran into a problem when the string literal was split between two lines. At that point I realized my means of checking if it was in an `X()` call was poor, because I'd have to keep adding `.Parent` to the chain. While I could write something to crawl backwards up the tree, that didn't seem like it was the right way (and probably wouldn't perform very well).

I've been trying to find a way, given a string literal syntax node, to determine if that is an argument in a method call. I haven't been able to find a decent way of going from the Syntax Tree to the Semantic Model to find what I'm looking for. I'm not even sure if that's the right approach, or if I'm missing something obvious.

I was able to use `SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPositionAsync` to get to the symbol, but that suffers from the same issue - I can't just pass the position of the string literal argument, I have to pass the position of the (correct) *parent* and I'm back where I started.

I'm hoping to avoid having to loop through the syntax tree multiple times, because that slows things way down. I can parse 553 files in about 1 second, but as soon as I try to loop to account for these multi-line situations, I'm up to about 12-13 seconds.

Just in case I've lost you in this novella (sorry), **here's what I'm hoping to figure out:** for a string literal being passed as an argument to a method, is there an easy way to determine what that method is?

Here is some example code - I've replaced calls to my `X()` function with `Convert.ToString` just to simulate the code I'm searching (I had to add references to one of our DLLs, so I switched calls to `Convert.ToString()` so I could just reference mscorlib for this example.

```
static void TestAttempt()
{

  string source = @"
  Imports System
  Namespace Exceptions
    Public NotInheritable Class ExampleException
      Inherits Validation

      Public Sub New()
        Convert.ToString(""Ignore me 1"")
        Console.WriteLine(""Report me"")
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(""Ignore me 2""))

        MyBase.New(Convert.ToString(""Ignore me 3, "" & _
                                    ""Because I'm already translated.""))
      End Sub
    End Class
  End Namespace";

  var tree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

  var syntaxRoot = tree.GetRoot();
  int i = 0;

  foreach (var s in syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<LiteralExpressionSyntax>())
  {
    // things to skip:
    if (s == null) { continue; }
    if (s.Kind() != SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression) { continue; }

    var Mscorlib = PortableExecutableReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll");
    var compilation = VisualBasicCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });
    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

    var symbol = SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPositionAsync(model, s.Parent.Parent.Parent.Span.Start, new AdhocWorkspace()).Result;

    if (symbol.ToDisplayString().EndsWith("Convert")) { continue; }

    Console.WriteLine(symbol);
    Console.WriteLine($"  Reported: {s.ToString()}");
    i++;
  }

  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine($"Total: {i}");
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `Dim str = "Ignore me?"\n Convert.ToString(str)`?

Comment: I'm trying to identify any string literal that isn't already wrapped in the `X()` function (which `Convert.ToString()` is standing in for in this example). Any string which is already wrapped I am just going to ignore.

Comment: So in my above example that means that you do want to report on the string literal. And do you want to report on `X(("str"))`? Note the extra parentheses. `"str"` is not directly used in `X`, so would you report on it? I don't think so. Where's the limit?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I misunderstood the question you were posing in your comment! Based on the way the system code works, I _would_ want to catch the string `Dim str = "Ignore me?"` because according to the standards, literals should be wrapped in `X()` and not pass variables into that function. And `X(("str"))` could be reported as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a warning that I have never used Roslyn before, and I normally code in VB.NET, I think I hacked together something that seems to do what you want (using LINQPad and lots of `Dump()` calls helped to find out what was going on).

```
void TestAttempt()
{

    string source = @"
  Imports System
  Namespace Exceptions
    Public NotInheritable Class ExampleException
      Inherits Validation

      Public Sub New()
        X(""Ignore me 1"")
        Console.WriteLine(""Report me"")
        Console.WriteLine(X(""Ignore me 2""))

        MyBase.New(X(""Ignore me 3, "" & _
                   ""Because I'm already translated.""))
      End Sub
    End Class
  End Namespace";

    var tree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

    var syntaxRoot = tree.GetRoot();
    int i = 0, notWrapped = 0;

    foreach (var s in syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<LiteralExpressionSyntax>())
    {
        // things to skip:
        if (s == null) { continue; }
        if (s.Kind() != SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression) { continue; }

        if (!IsWrappedInCallToX(s))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  Reported: {s.ToString()}");
            notWrapped++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Total: {i}, Not Wrapped In X: {notWrapped}");
}

bool IsWrappedInCallToX(SyntaxNode node)
{
    var invocation = node as InvocationExpressionSyntax;
    if (invocation != null)
    {
        var exp = invocation.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax;
        if (exp != null && exp.ToString() == "X")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (node.Parent != null)
    {
        return IsWrappedInCallToX(node.Parent);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This results in:

```
  Reported: "Report me"

Total: 5, Not Wrapped In X: 1
```

The `IsWrappedInCallToX` function just recurses up the tree looking for an `InvocationExpressionSyntax` for the `X` function.  I know you said "While I could write something to crawl backwards up the tree, that didn't seem like it was the right way (and probably wouldn't perform very well)", but to me it seems like this is the right way - if the performance is horrible on your code base, maybe not!

Again, I know nothing about Roslyn (this just sounded interesting), so this is very likely a terrible solution! :-)

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's a terrible solution or not, but it definitely helped me! The logic I had used to crawl up the tree was just poor, and I think I ended up crawling the entire way up the tree every time because I was using Parent. I had to modify your solution somewhat as I discovered other edge cases I needed to ignore (Attributes, certain constructors that ultimately translate the string, etc.) but this was a great foundation. Oh, and it's also still very fast. The old utility takes 30+ seconds to parse this one project - my prototype just ran in 0.44 seconds.

Comment: Another tip for others new to Roslyn - check out the Syntax Visualizer window (available if you have the .NET Compiler Platform SDK extension installed in VS2015). I really wish I'd known about that earlier this week, would have saved me a ton of time and helped me understand the syntax tree without stepping through code and looking at the watch window.